# Comm command - unnecessary restriction?

Tags: linux, command-line

This is a question about the `comm` command on linux command line.

Why does it work on only sorted files? Why can't it sort the files for us, then do its thing? To illustrate: If we have `file1` and `file2`, and we wish to compare them using `comm`, we find that we obtain an unexpected result if either of the two files is NOT sorted. Why did the creators add this restriction of mandating the arguments to be SORTED files?

This seems inconvenient, and I feel like creating a shell script to replace this default `comm`.

My question is: why shouldn't I replace it? Is it a good thing to have this restriction with `comm`, like how `const` is something that we may add in a c++ program that's unnecessary, but deemed as good practice?

Thanks.

Comment: The original Unix philosophy was that each command should do just one simple thing, and you should use piping and other command composition techniques to combine them to get your desired result.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll keep that in mind when I'm playing with the other commands, thanks.

Comment: BTW, `comm` isn't the only command like this. `uniq` is similar, it only compares adjacent lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design keeps the `comm` program simple, all it has to do is compare the files. If it had to sort the files as well, it would much of the complexity of the `sort` command, including the need for temporary files if the contents don't fit into memory. And this would be unnecessary if the files were already sorted. The basic Unix philosophy is that each command should do one thing, or maybe a few variations of that thing based on options, and you should combine them for more complex needs.

You can use process substitution to sort the files before comparing them.

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```